# Intermittent Curl Error (28) Timeout - Different Results on Different Locations

Tags: ubuntu, curl, digital-ocean

I'm new here.

I have a curl request that I need to use when receiving payments on my e-shop installed on Digitalocean and Ubuntu 20.04 server.

I am having an intermittent and completely random curl response problem.
This is a very simple form sent from my server to the bank's server via curl.

Sometimes the bank's server responds to this transaction on the first attempt, sometimes not even after a few attempts. Sometimes it fails on the first attempt, sometimes it completes successfully on the 2nd or 3rd attempt. Sometimes it works for a few hours without any errors and then it starts giving errors again. It is completely random and intermittent.

When it fails, it gives the error "Curl: (28) sanalposprov.garanti.com.tr port 443: Connection timed out."
My Droplet is located in Frankfurt and the bank is located in Turkey.

To see if the problem is caused by the server, I created a new droplet, installed Ubuntu 20.04 again and sent the same curl request to the bank's address from the console without installing anything else. The result did not change, the same problem was occurring on a new and clean server.

After that, I tried to create new servers in different locations on digitalocean, Amsterdam and Frankfurt had the same problematic result in all cases. On the London and New York servers, each request was responded without any problem.

By the way, when I made similar tests from a server located in Turkey, I was able to get a response without any problems.

I cannot understand that this situation differs according to the locations. When we contact the bank, they say that there is no problem on their servers and that it may be related to our server. Similar things when we contact Digitalocean.

I need any idea you can suggest on how I can solve this situation. Thank you in advance.